# Codeigniter upload issue

Tags: codeigniter

my site is working fine on my local server
but when i upload it on my host it shows this error

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: require_once(/home/content/49/7388549/html/awt/system/database/drivers/PDO/PDO_driver.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Filename: database/DB.php

Line Number: 140


Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/home/content/49/7388549/html/awt/system/database/drivers/PDO/PDO_driver.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php5/lib/php') in /home/content/49/7388549/html/awt/system/database/DB.php on line 140
```

any help would be appreciated
Thanks in advance

Comment: Does the `system/database/drivers/PDO/PDO_driver.php` file exist?

Comment: Make sure your config files are set up correctly. Your CI install may be referring to a location that exists on your local machine, but is slightly different on your GoDaddy box.

Comment: @jeemusu yes the file exists.

Comment: @DavidHoude how do i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Please kindly check `system/database/drivers/PDO/PDO_driver.php` file is present or not in your application. If not the copy this file to the location